# Как вывести сообщение при загрузке страницы?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Привет всем. Есть код, при нажатии на ссылку появляется сообщение. А как сделать, чтобы это сообщение появлялось при загрузке страницы?

Вот сам код:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.extend($.gritter.options, {
        position: 'bottom-right',
        fade_in_speed: 1000,
        fade_out_speed: 1000,
        time: 3000
    });
    $('#add-regular').click(function () {
        $.gritter.add({
            title: 'Тема:',
            text: 'Сообщение!',
            image: 'http://a0.twimg.com/profile_images/59268975/jquery_avatar_bigger.png',
            sticky: false,
            time: '5000'
        });
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: при добавлении кода обведи его и нажми на кнопу 01010 в редакторе

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#add-regular').click();
```

это сымитирует клик по объекту, помести его в domready

**Добавлено из комментария**.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.extend($.gritter.options, {
            position: 'bottom-right',
            fade_in_speed: 1000,
            fade_out_speed: 1000,
            time: 3000
        });
        $('#add-regular').click(function () {
            $.gritter.add({
                title: 'Тема:',
                text: 'Сообщение!',
                image: 'http://a0.twimg.com/profile_images/59268975/jquery_avatar_bigger.png',
                sticky: false,
                time: '5000'
            });
            return false;
        });
        $('#add-regular').click();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: только помести после навешивания самого события

Comment: Перенесено в ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Тут [подробно расписано](http://ruseller.com/adds.php?rub=11&id=2106), как использовать и настраивать данный плагин (**Gritter**).